# Using Different Representations of a Single Value Object

Tags: c#, .net, architecture, domain-driven-design, value-objects

I am working in the domain of industrial automation. This software will control several pieces of industrial equipment using serial connections and protocols designed by the manufacturer of each piece of equipment. I have created Value Objects for common parameters such as Distance, Voltage, etc., however, each piece of equipment expects a different representation of the value and the UI still another.

As an example, suppose I need to adjust the location of an object by 1 centimeter. Equipment #1 expects distances to be in meters, Equipment #2 expects distances to be in microns, and the UI expects centimeters. I plan to use the MKS system so my Distance Value Object stores the quantity in meters.

From the book *Implementing Domain Driven Design* by Vaughn Vernon, my value objects seem as though they should satisfy the characteristics of a Value Object as he describes, namely:

1. It measures, quantifies, or describes a thing in the domain.
2. It can be maintained as immutable.
3. It models a conceptual whole by composing related attributes as an integral unit.
4. It is completely replaceable when the measurement or description changes.
5. It can be compared with others using Value equality.
6. It supplies its collaborators with Side-Effect-Free Behavior

**Thought 1:** Add the twelve common metric prefixes to each Value Object class.

```
public class Distance
{
    private readonly double quantity; // in meters

    public Distance(double distance)
    {
        quantity = distance;
    }

    public double AsCentimeters()
    {
        return quantity * 100;
    }
}
```

This approach seems incorrect since the calculations based on the prefixes will not change and will have to be duplicated in several Value Objects.

**Thought 2:** Introduce an enumeration with the metric prefixes and a base class with the calculations.

```
public enum SIPrefix
{
    None, Centi 
};

public class SIUnitBase
{
    protected readonly double quantity;

    public double Value(SIPrefix prefix)
    {
        switch (prefix)
        {
            case SIPrefix.Centi:
                return quantity * 100;
                break;
            default:
                return quantity;
                break;
        }
    }
}

public class Distance : SIUnitBase
{
    public Distance(double distance)
    {
        quantity = distance;
    }
}

// ... in code ...
Distance d = new Distance(1.0, SIPrefix.None);
Equipment.Move(d.Value(SIPrefix.Centi));
```

This approach seems both verbose and error prone.

**Thought 3:** Create a set of extension methods to add the required functionality.

```
public static class DistanceExtensions
{
    public static double AsCentimeters(this Distance distance)
    {
        return distance * 100;
    }
}
```

This approach seems almost as verbose as **Thought 1**, but I could only implement the conversions I need for the specific application.

**How should I model this architecture so that I can provide each Domain Object and UI the Value Object in the representation it expects?**

A search for previous value object questions only revealed [one thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489701/value-object-getter) similar to my issue.

Comment: I can go with **Thought 3**. Note it's just a problem in how to display the results for the user ans it ill require one more parameter (unit used) in a range o know units (enum?). The UI just needs to display the value based on the persited value and unit used for that property

Comment: **Thought 4** - use F#'s [Units of Measure](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/units-of-measure/) if switching language is still an option at that point

Comment: @guillaume31 Not sure it's worth switching language for such a simple problem.

Comment: @plalx problem might be simple but the C# implementation much less so IMO :)

Comment: @guillaume31 Can't you just implement something similar to what I proposed? Perhaps I also misunderstood the question, but it seems quite easy to build a `Distance` VO that can be represented in any units and handles conversion rates.

Comment: @plalx You could probably do it in 10x less LoC in F# and it would be less cumbersome to use since the feature is baked in the language, but yes I suppose the C# implementation would be similar to yours. F# would give you stronger type checking though.

Comment: @guillaume31 I added a C# sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The design of your value objects is good. Encapsulating e.g. a distance and and providing one accessor for the main unit (e.g. meters) is all the value object needs.

**The software itself should be able to use only these value objects (without accessing the raw value) to maintain a meaningful model.** So you will likely need addition and subtraction operators on these value objects as well, probably also others. **The goal here is that users of the VO never need to think about the specific unit used** (except for obvious cases like construction).

But the fact that different `Equipment` requires different representations is not something you should tackle with additional accessors (or extension methods), **because that muddies your VOs and as a result your model becomes less succinct.**

I suggest you define an interface for your `Equipment` that uses your VOs. Then, create an [adapter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) that knows about the specific units of an `Equipment`. The adapter is resposible for converting between your standardized VOs and the specifics of the `Equipment`.

Comment: I believe your response best answers the spirit of my question with a concise architectural solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the concept of a unit and a conversion ratio. I do not know the c# syntax very well, so I just wrote the sample in JavaScript:

```js
//This would be an enum holding conversion ratios to meters
var units = {
  cm: 0.01,
  dm: 0.1,
  m: 1,
  km: 1000,
  assertValidUnit: function(unit) {
    if (!this.hasOwnProperty(unit)) throw new Error('Invalid unit: ' + unit);
  }
};


function Distance(value, unit) {
  units.assertValidUnit(unit);
  this.value = value;
  this.unit = unit;
}

Distance.prototype = {
  constructor: Distance,
  
  in: function(unit) {
    units.assertValidUnit(unit);
    return new Distance(this.value * (units[this.unit] / units[unit]), unit);
  },

  plus: function (distance) {
      var otherDistanceValueInCurrentUnit = distance.in(this.unit).value;

      return new Distance(this.value + otherDistanceValueInCurrentUnit, this.unit);
  },

  minus: function (distance) {
      var otherDistanceValueInCurrentUnit = distance.in(this.unit).value;

      return new Distance(this.value - otherDistanceValueInCurrentUnit, this.unit);
  },

  toString: function() {
    return this.value + this.unit;
  }
};

var oneKm = new Distance(1, 'km'),
  oneM = new Distance(1, 'm'),
  twoCm = new Distance(2, 'cm');

log(oneM + ' + ' + oneKm + ' is ' + oneM.plus(oneKm));
log(oneM + ' - ' + twoCm + ' is ' + oneM.minus(twoCm).in('cm'));

convertAndLog(oneKm, 'm');
convertAndLog(oneKm, 'cm');
convertAndLog(oneM, 'dm');
convertAndLog(oneM, 'km');


function convertAndLog(distance, unit) {
  var convertedDistance = distance.in(unit),
      msg = distance + ' is ' + convertedDistance;
  
  log(msg);
}

function log(msg) {
  document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(msg));
  document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
}
```

Your `Equipment` can deal with `Distance` directly and use `distance.in` internally to make sure it's working with the correct units.

```
function Equipment(distanceUnit) {
    this.distanceUnit = distanceUnit;
}

Equipment.prototype.move = function (distance) {
    alert('Moved equipment by ' + distance.in(this.distanceUnit));
};

var equipment = new Equipment('cm');

equipment.move(new Distance(5.4, 'dm')); //Moved equipment by 54cm
```

It might not be idiomatic C# at all, but here's an attempt:

```
//Values stored as unit/m * 1000 to avoid enum float limitations
public enum MeasureUnit {cm = 10, dm = 100, m = 1000, km = 1000000}

public static class MesureUnitExtension {
  public static float Ratio(this MeasureUnit e) {
    return (float)e / (float)1000.0;
  }
}

public class Measure {
    private float value;
    private MeasureUnit unit;

    public Measure(float value, MeasureUnit unit) {
        this.value = value;
        this.unit = unit;
    }

    public Measure In(MeasureUnit unit) {
        return new Measure(this.value * (this.unit.Ratio() / unit.Ratio()), this.unit);
    }

    public override string ToString() {
        return this.value.ToString() + this.unit.ToString();
    }
}
```